# How to solve $\frac {dx}{dt} = \frac {1}{x} - \frac {x}{4}$ for $x^2$ in terms of $t$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $x = 1$ when $t = 0$, solve the differential equation $$\frac {dx}{dt} = \frac {1}{x} - \frac {x}{4},$$

obtaining an expression for $x^2 $ in terms of $t$.

How do I do this?

Comment: Just separate variables: $\frac{4x}{4-x^2}dx=dt$.

Comment: How do you integrate the LHS?

Comment: Perform a simple $u$-substitution...........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separable?

$$\int\frac{dx}{\frac1x-\frac x4}=\int\ dt=t+c$$

Now let $u=4-x^2$.

$$\int\frac{dx}{\frac1x-\frac x4}=\int\frac{4x\ dx}{4-x^2}=-2\int\frac{du}u=-2\ln|u|=-2\ln|4-x^2|$$

Thus,

> $$-2\ln|4-x^2|=t+c$$

Comment: OP asks for "an expression for $x^2$ in terms of t". So $x^2=4-e^\frac{t+c}{-2}$

Comment: Yup, that would finish it all off... assuming certain signs in the absolute value bars.

Comment: Oh, forgot about that.